# How to delete all directories below a certain depth?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm using Minecraft [Overviewer](http://docs.overviewer.org/en/latest/) to generate a world map, however, a great deal more directories (and subdirectories) are being generated than I need.  The hierarchy represents a [quad-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), and the zoom levels match the number of levels down it creates these folders.

[image]

For the inquisitive among you, [the documentation](http://docs.overviewer.org/en/latest/config/?highlight=zoom) does point out that you can set `maxzoom` in the configuration file, however, this is a user-interface limitation, not a practical one.  As noted:

> This does not change the number of zoom levels rendered, but allows
>   you to neglect uploading the larger and more detailed zoom levels if
>   bandwidth usage is an issue.

What I need is a way to delete all subdirectories past a certain depth (say 4 levels deep).  I know that `del` is for deleting files, `rmdir` is for removing directories, and that `*` is considered a wildcard.  Therefore, I assumed I may simply need to write...

```
rmdir */*/*/*
```

Sadly, it generates the following error: `Invalid switch - "*",`

Perhaps it was having issue with the forward slashes?  In which case I tried...

```
rmdir *\*\*\*
```

However, that generated the following error: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

Please help?

Comment: What does `rmdir /?` tell you??

Comment: @abelenky: "Removes (deletes) a directory.  RMDIR [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path.  RD [/S] [/Q] [drive:]path.  /S removes all directories and files in the specified directory in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove directory tree.  /Q quiet mode, do not ask if ok to remove a directory tree with /S"

Comment: You could four nested `FOR /D` commands to get to the depth that you need then use the `RMDIR` command at that 4th level

Comment: Just an idea, but have you tried/considered including the `RoboCopy` command with `/E /Move /Lev:4`?

Comment: @Compo: I was not aware of RoboCopy.  I'm actually shocked as this honestly does work (thank you!), but not the way I was hoping.  I still feel like my original question hasn't been answered.  For posterity the full command is as follows:  `RoboCopy sourceDir destinationDir /E /Move /Lev:4`

Comment: Something like `rmdir *\*\*\*` cannot work because wildcards (`*`, `?`) can only be used in the very last element of a path...

Comment: @Atriace, you asked, "What I need is a way to delete all subdirectories past a certain depth (say 4 levels deep)." `RoboCopy` with the options I gave you, does exactly that; yes it may need an additional rename, remove and/or delete sequence to tidy things up but I reckon you won't get anything more simple. Can I ask why you feel that the original question hasn't been answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my opening comment, you could use `RoboCopy` for this:

```bat
@Ren "sourceDir\" "tempName"
@RoboCopy "tempName" "sourceDir" /E /Move /Lev:4
```

---

You could also use `PowerShell` to do this as it allows for the kind of wildcard pattern you were hoping for.

Version 3.0+, *(Win8+)*:

```ps1
Get-ChildItem '.\*\*\*\*' -Directory -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

…and with aliases:

```ps1
Ls '.\*\*\*\*' -Di -R|Rm -R -Fo -EA SilentlyContinue
```

Version 2.0, *(Win7+)*:

```ps1
Get-ChildItem '.\*\*\*\*' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

…and with aliases:

```ps1
Ls '.\*\*\*\*' -R|?{$_.PSIsContainer}|Rm -R -Fo -EA SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this script. It will remove all folders with a level deeper than 4 starting from a current folder. E. g. if you have folders `1\2\3\4\5\6\7` and the script is in folder `1` then it will remove folders starting from `6` and below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call :deeptree 0 4
goto :eof

:deeptree
for /d %%p in (*.*) do (
   if %1 lss %2 (
      pushd "%%p"
      set /a l=%1+1
      echo Level !l! %%p
      call :deeptree !l! %2
      popd
   ) else (
      echo removing %%p
      rd /s /q "%%p"
   )
)
```

Comment: Actually it does not really matter where the script is, the current working directory needs to be `1`; nice recursive approach anyway...

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, you're correct, I've just put it in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply nest several [`for /D` loops](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html), like this:

```cmd
for /D %%A in ("D:\Root\Path\Day\*") do (
    for /D %%B in ("%%~A\*") do (
        for /D %%C in ("%%~B\*") do (
            for /D %%D in ("%%~C\*") do (
                for /D %%E in ("%%~D\*") do (
                    rmdir /S /Q "%%~E"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```